# jQuery Accordian crash on large data set

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

jQuery accordian works fine for small data sets.

Only when datasets gets large it seems to become unresponsive.

Also, it becomes responsive again if atleast one node/header is kept opened. Not sure whats happening behind the scene. Any clue?

Comment: Can you post some code for accordion implementation.where the data comes from.?